# .Net Core Api - Token Based Authentication Restrict Delete Any Record In A Table Problem

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing Web API on .NET Core. I added authentication method that is token based authentication(JWT) to verify user. I can generate a token for a user and validate the token if it is expired or not. But, I tried to delete B user's record with A user's token and B user's record deleted succesfully with A user's token. How can I restrict users, so they can only delete their own records?

I couldn't find any solution for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle this kind of validation manually. A jwt token should contain the user's ID, if the authentication is properly configured in you app, you should be able to access the requestor user's ID from the access token similarly to this:

```
User.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value;
```

You can check the contents of your jwt token on https://jwt.io/.

After you have the userID you can return e.g. 403 HTTP Status code, when the user ID in the jwt token is different from the user ID of the record to delete.